# Reuse the credentials of one system to Log in to another

Tags: python, authentication, ldap, apache-superset, flask-appbuilder

I'm new to Flask, I'm using the apache-superset in version 0.38.0.

In it I'm using an LDAP authentication method, everything is functional.

However, I have another system in the company, which also uses LDAP to login, proprietary system. The idea is that when the user is logged in to our system and is going to enter the superset, he is already logged in, taking advantage of the credentials used in our system, since both are use LDAP.

What I've found so far: Apparently this is the class that authenticates LDAP credentials:

```
class AuthLDAPView(AuthView):
    login_template = "appbuilder/general/security/login_ldap.html"

    @expose("/login/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
    def login(self):
        if g.user is not None and g.user.is_authenticated:
            return redirect(self.appbuilder.get_url_for_index)
        form = LoginForm_db()
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            user = self.appbuilder.sm.auth_user_ldap(
                form.username.data, form.password.data
            )
            if not user:
                flash(as_unicode("Usuário não Encontrado ou Instabilidade no servidor LDAP"), "warning")
                return redirect(self.appbuilder.get_url_for_login)
            login_user(user, remember=False)
            return redirect(self.appbuilder.get_url_for_index)
        return self.render_template(
            self.login_template, title=self.title, form=form, appbuilder=self.appbuilder
        )
```

the credentials apparently received through LoginForm_db ():

```
class LoginForm_db(DynamicForm):
username = StringField(lazy_gettext("User Name"), validators=[DataRequired()])
password = PasswordField(lazy_gettext("Password"), validators=[DataRequired()])
```

which in turn receives the values ​​from the login screen that is written in flask in the following:

```
 <form class="form" action="" method="post" name="login">
    {{form.hidden_tag()}}
    <div class="help-block">{{_("Enter your login and password below")}}:</div>
    <div class="control-group{% if form.errors.openid is defined %} error{% endif %}">
        <label class="control-label" for="openid">{{_("Username")}}:</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
            {{ form.username(size = 80, class = "form-control", autofocus = true) }}
            </div>
            {% for error in form.errors.get('openid', []) %}
                <span class="help-inline">[{{error}}]</span><br>
            {% endfor %}
    <label class="control-label" for="openid">{{_("Password")}}:</label>
            <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-key"></i></span>
            {{ form.password(size = 80, class = "form-control") }}
            </div>
            {% for error in form.errors.get('openid', []) %}
                <span class="help-inline">[{{error}}]</span><br>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="control-group">
        <div class="controls">
    <br>
            <input class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" value="{{_('Logar')}}">
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

I was thinking of doing something that can send the credentials authenticated in our proprietary system (developed in java) through the url and receive them in this form of the superset and consequently log in.

I'm almost sure it shouldn't be the safest method, but I'm a beginner in programming and can't think of anything better. Maybe the Token but I don't even know where to start.

User logged into another system, (where I can redeem the user and password), when redirected to the superset, must be automatically logged in. How to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a RESTful API to handle user authentication as below

```
from flask import request, make_response, jsonify, session
from flask_appbuilder.api import BaseApi, expose, rison, safe
from flask_appbuilder.security.decorators import protect

from . import appbuilder
from flask_login import current_user, login_user
from app import db



class LoginApi(BaseApi):

    resource_name = "login"
    
    @expose('/loginapi/', methods=['GET','POST'])
    #@has_access
    
    def loginapi(self):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            username = request.json['username']
            password = request.json['password']

            user = self.appbuilder.sm.auth_user_db(username, password)
            
            
            if str(user) != "None":
               
              login_user(user, remember=False)
              if current_user.is_active:
               username = current_user.username
               status  = current_user.active
               response = make_response(jsonify({'message': 'Login Success',
                                  'severity': 'info','Username': 
                                                           username,'Status':status}))
        return response
```

For details on how to create a REST API refer to this this.
https://flask-appbuilder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/rest_api.html